# How can I find pdf and epub files that contain multiple keywords in same page?

Tags: pdf, search

I have a big directory which has a lot of pdf and epub ebook files. I want to search that files that contain multiple keywords on the same page.

Answer (score 2):

### PDF

Pick any utility that can extract text from a single page (e.g. `pdftext`), iterate over all pages and extract text, apply regexp to extracted text.

Or, use a programming language of your choice, a PDF library of your choice, and write a program for it.

### EPUB

An epub is just a zip file. Unzip it, and you get lots of html files. You can scan these files for regular expressions, or use some tool to convert them to plain text first, ignoring the formatting.

Note that an epub file fundamentally *does not have pages*: Pagination will be done by the rendering device, and will be potentially different for every rendering device. So "looking for multiple keywords on the same page" must be changed somehow to take this into account, possibly using the html structure.